# I can't add application in itunes connect in my apple developer account

Tags: ios, iphone

when I click on iTunes Connect

[image]

apple forwarded me to this page, and I can't add application

[image]

when click on apps, this page is opened:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you click "Apps"?

Comment: check update in question